# React: getBoundingClientRect get position of previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getboundingclientrect

first, [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/getboundingclientrect-chaos-gsnj5) demonstrating the issue.

we have 2 components - `DraggableBox` which is a wrapper around [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable) and `SimpleArrow` which is a much simplified version of [react-xarrows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xarrows)(I'm the author).

we can see a visual bug and that's because both `DraggableBox` and `SimpleArrow` update their state based on the same DOM frame(and the same react render phase - useEffect), while `SimpleArrow` should be updated based on the position of `DraggableBox`.

we could solve it if we would force 2 renders for each render on 'SimpleArrow', and then on the 2'th render 'SimpleArrow' will read the updated 'DraggableBox' position. we can force 2 renders by writing a custom hook:

```js
export const useMultipleRenders = (renders = 2, effect = useEffect) => {
  const [, setRender] = useState({});
  const reRender = () => setRender({});
  const count = useRef(0);
  effect(() => {
    if (count.current != renders) {
      reRender();
      count.current += 1;
    } else {
      count.current = 0;
    }
  });
};
```

now we will consume `useMultipleRenders()` on `SimpleArrow` and the visual glitch would be fixed.

[here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/getboundingclientrect-chaos-with-ugly-workaround-fhxdz) a code sandbox with the fix. you can see this ugly workaround works.

this actually happens all the time in React when accessing the DOM.
you access the dom during a render using a ref (useRef) value, and during this render, you can only have access to what is currently in the dom, which is the result of the previous render, but you actually need the result of the current render!

for example, in `SimpleArrow` I'm using `getBoundingClientRect` on the inner of the svg to determine the svg hight and width:

```js
const SimpleArrow = (props) => {
  const svgInnersRef = useRef<SVGGElement>(null);
  const {
    width: gWidth,
    height: gHeight
  } = svgInnersRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect() ?? { width: 0, height: 0 };
  return (
    <svg
      width={gWidth}
      height={gHeight}
      // ...
    >
      <g ref={svgInnersRef}>
      {/* ... */}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

but in order to make sure the height and width are updated I have to double render so I get the right dimensions on the last render.

another thing is that the implementation of `useMultipleRenders` is not safe as it changing ref value during a render. React core members [claims](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21956#issuecomment-893049807) that setting ref value during a render is not safe.

what can I do? what are the alternatives?

### TLDR;

1. can I get the most updated position of a DOM element without manually rerender?
2. how can I manually re-render without changing a ref value during a render(as it is not safe - on React strict mode it will be called twice and normally only once)?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem and I am not sure I understand fully, but here's a shot.

You could try adding a `drag` event listener inside of `SimpleArrow.js`.

When there is a drag, you would check if it is one of your draggable boxes, and then if it is, you update their positions with a setState, which should trigger a rerender of your `svg` component and with the new positions of the boxes.

Comment: thanks for the shot friend, but guess you did not fully understand - please read again the question and my proposed solution and see if you can suggest an alternative.  also - please don't consider using outside react event listeners (like elem.addEventListener) because it works outside the lifecycle of my component